# Pasting formula in non-adjacent cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table in a sheet. A cell in this table contains a formula referencing a cell from another sheet like below.

[image: My Sample Table]

Here, Table-Date1's E3 contains reference to `=Nur!G44`, but when I copy this Date1 table and paste to create Date2, Cell I3 in Date2 table is coming as `=Nur!K44`, but here I would like to have `=Nur!H44` i.e. the column should be incremented just as pasted in an adjacent cell. How to do that? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula needs to offset by 1 taking into account an increase of 4 columns each time starting at column 5, so you should be able to use:

=OFFSET(Nur!$G44,0,(COLUMN()-5)/4,1,1)